# How do you make a Canon 70D show the photo you just took on the rear display?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, display, image-review

How do you make the Canon 70D show the pic you just took on the rear display?  I have to press the arrow to turn it on every time.  All other Canons show it for just a second immediately after taking it.  I am not talking about live mode.

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Comment: yes I have looked all through it but can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 7):

Check how the image review time is set on your camera. It sounds like yours has somehow been set to `Off`. These are the instructions from p.60 of the [70D manual](https://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/90467.pdf):

[image: 70D manual p.60 instructions on image review time]

If you set `Hold`, the image will be displayed for the same amount of time you have set for auto power-off.

Comment: awesome exactly what I needed.

Comment: @LanaHager Glad to help. Because this is SE, and not a messageboard, consider [accepting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), or (when you get the rep) [upvoting](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) an answer instead of a thanks comment. Please, take [the tour](http://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) if you plan to stick around.